# RegEx for all strings with certain number

Tags: java, regex

I want to identify all strings that contain the number `5` after `finger_` or `ground_`. This should ignore the number at the end (regardless of if it ends with `phase_` or `env_`).

Here are some examples:

```
finger_5_ground_4_phase_92 = YES
finger_1_ground_2_phase_9 = NO
finger_4_ground_2_phase_5 = NO
finger_4_ground_2_env_5 = NO
finger_4_ground_5_env_5 = YES
```

Comment: `(?:finger|ground)_5_`

Comment: What language will  you be using?  Different languages may have slightly different regex syntax/support...

Comment: @TJSaunders I'll be using Java

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use this:

```
.*(finger|ground)_5_.*
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the `*` characters? That will treat them literally, but there are no `*` characters in the strings.

Comment: the * character in regex means zero or more times and . character means any character.

Comment: I know what it means. But escaping it with backslash disables that meaning.

Comment: There's also no need to escape `_`, it doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: My bad, I just copy and forgot to remove the backslash

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(?:finger|ground)_5.*");
    System.out.println(String.format("%s = %s", "finger_5_ground_4_phase_92", pattern.matcher("finger_5_ground_4_phase_92").matches() ? "YES" : "NO"));
    System.out.println(String.format("%s = %s", "finger_1_ground_2_phase_9", pattern.matcher("finger_1_ground_2_phase_9").matches() ? "YES" : "NO"));
    System.out.println(String.format("%s = %s", "finger_4_ground_2_phase_5", pattern.matcher("finger_4_ground_2_phase_5").matches() ? "YES" : "NO"));
    System.out.println(String.format("%s = %s", "finger_4_ground_2_env_5", pattern.matcher("finger_4_ground_2_env_5").matches() ? "YES" : "NO"));
    System.out.println(String.format("%s = %s", "finger_4_ground_5_env_5", pattern.matcher("finger_4_ground_5_env_5").matches() ? "YES" : "NO"));
```